# XSLT & XML Help - Not generating html with two different XML elements

Tags: xml, xslt, dom, xml-parsing

I have a problem with combining my XSLT and XML in a certain situation and I am stuck, below is an example of my issue:

XML:

```
<a>
<x>
    <y testname="test1">
      <object elementname="Name" elementvalue="true" elementvalue1="ABC" elementvalue2="ADF">
        <comparisonresult>false</comparisonresult>
      </object>
     </y>

</x>
</a>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <font face="Arial">
        <h2>HEADINGY</h2>
        <h4>Process 1</h4>
        <h4>More Process</h4>
            <h4>Additional </h4>
              <table border="1">
              <tr bgcolor="#dccdc">
                <th align="center">T1</th>
                <th align="center">T2</th>
                <th align="center">T3</th>
              </tr>
              </table>
          <h2>Main</h2>
          <xsl:for-each select="a/x/y">
            <h3>
              <xsl:value-of select="@testname" />
            </h3>
            <h4>Heading 1</h4>
            <table border="1" style="display:inline">
              <tr bgcolor="#CECEF6">
                <th align="center">Item1</th>
                <th align="center">Item2</th>
                <th align="center">Item3</th>
              </tr>
              <xsl:for-each select="object">
                <tr>
                  <td bgcolor="#F2F5A9">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@elementname" />
                  </td>
                  <td bgcolor="#F2F5A9">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@elementvalue1" />
                  </td>
                  <td bgcolor="#F2F5A9">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@elementvalue2" />
                  </td>

                </tr>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </font>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you enter these two into http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=simple&xsltfile=simple you get output as expected. The issue comes when i added the following to the XML, so it looks like:

```
<a>
<x>
    <y testname="test1">
      <object elementname="Name" elementvalue="true" elementvalue1="ABC" elementvalue2="ADF">
        <comparisonresult>false</comparisonresult>
      </comparisonobject>
</y>
<x>

 <t testname="ComparisonResult">
    <step stepname="Add x" stepresult="Add x">
      <result>true</result>
    </step>
</t>



</a>
```

and the corresponding xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <font face="Arial">
        <h2>HEADINGY</h2>
        <h4>Process 1</h4>
        <h4>More Process</h4>
          <xsl:for-each select="a/x/t">
             <xsl:for-each select="testname">
            <h4>Additional </h4>
              <table border="1">
              <tr bgcolor="#dccdc">
                <th align="center">T1</th>
                <th align="center">T2</th>
                <th align="center">T3</th>
              </tr>

 <xsl:for-each select="stepname">
                <tr>
                  <td bgcolor="#F2F5A9">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@stepname" />
                  </td>
                  <td bgcolor="#F2F5A9">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@step result" />
                  </td>
                  <td bgcolor="#F2F5A9">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@result" />
                  </td>
              </table>
          <h2>Main</h2>
          <xsl:for-each select="a/x/y">
            <h3>
              <xsl:value-of select="@testname" />
            </h3>
            <h4>Heading 1</h4>
            <table border="1" style="display:inline">
              <tr bgcolor="#CECEF6">
                <th align="center">Item1</th>
                <th align="center">Item2</th>
                <th align="center">Item3</th>
              </tr>
              <xsl:for-each select="object">
                <tr>
                  <td bgcolor="#F2F5A9">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@elementname" />
                  </td>
                  <td bgcolor="#F2F5A9">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@elementvalue1" />
                  </td>
                  <td bgcolor="#F2F5A9">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@elementvalue2" />
                  </td>

                </tr>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </font>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I just get a blank page.
I know there is a lot here to digest, but im really stuck!

Thanks

Comment: Your stylesheet is not wellformed...

Comment: Your xml is also not well formed. Make your x and y tags match up.

Comment: I can see the mistake in the XML but am unsure about the XSLT where im going wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<xsl:for-each select="a/x/t">` doesn't match your document structure - it should be `<xsl:for-each select="a/t">` ... but your nested `for-each` bear further problems.

What you are trying to achieve is better done using templates. I'll add an example later.